response payload missing last character
authRouter.post("/checkEmail", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.body;
    if (!email) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ error: "Email address is missing in the request body." });
    }
    const query = "SELECT auth.is_email_exist($1);";
    const result = await pool.query(query, [email]);
    const isEmailExist = result.rows[0].is_email_exist;
    res.json(isEmailExist);
    console.log(isEmailExist);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error checking email:", err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});

This post request always gives the correct response but the request gets blocked as the response last character always gets ommitted and it is only happening with this request
I have set the content header encoding to UTF8


EDIT 1
Still the same error with response payload missing error causing json.parse error,request status 200 and request being blocked by devtools but one more thing observed all requests have ns_error_net_partial_transfer
here are the results of the things suggested

Checking response data:
correct response data on console.log() but even if res.send(hello) is sent there is the same error
[4/9/2024, 8:45:03 AM] info: Incoming request: POST /api/V1/auth/checkEmail
false

using postman
postman gives correct response and correct status code 200 without any errors

Client side code
axios gives error response in front end

setting different content type
set the content type to text\plain now no json parse error but the request is still blocked by devtools and has same net partial error

Checked all middlewares and every request working just except this



Add res.send('hello'); return; as the first line of your function and run the request. If the response is not hello then you have a problem with some handler or middleware that is executed after your POST handler.

I'd also test from another client, eg curl or Postman

Sounds like the issue is client-side. Do you get the same problem in a different browser? If so, I'd be looking at any Axios interceptors or response transformers you may have added. If not, I'd be suspicious of any browser extensions you're running

Finally after trying everything found the error in the axios request
const res = await axios.post("https://localhost:5050/api/V1/auth/checkEmail", { email });

but had already set the proxy target to https://localhost:5050 in vite so changed above to
const res = await axios.post("/api/V1/auth/checkEmail", { email });

and the request worked. Ps thx for the help

I can not possibly see how this would cause an issue parsing the response

dont know but after changing this the request succeeded
